# Publish ASP.Net website using MSBuild API

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

I am trying to build a website project and publish into a folder using MSBuild API

```
 using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
 using Microsoft.Build.Execution;
 using Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine;


 var props = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                            { "Configuration", "Release" },   
                            { "DeployOnBuild","true"},
                            { "WebPublishMethod", "FileSystem"}                                 
                            { "PublishDir", "C:\Published\MySite\"},
                            { "OutDir", "C:\Published\MySite\"},
                    };

        var projPath = "C:\Projects\MySite.csproj";

        var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(
            new BuildParameters { Loggers = new[] { new ConsoleLogger() } },
            new BuildRequestData(new ProjectInstance(projPath, props, null), new[] { "Build" }));

        if (result.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded!");
        }
```

The problem is its not moving the published version like how I do via VisualStudio->Right click-> Publish.

But currently its creating content like below structure, which I dont want

```
"C:\Published\MySite\"
   all bin content(*.dll)
   _PublishedWebsite
       ActualContent I Expected
       Package (it has compressed version)
```

All I need is just build & publish the content to the folder "C:\Published\MySite\"

Do any one help me anything wrong with my `props` / configurations?

Comment: Maybe `OutDir` and `PublishDir` should be different? Isn't the former a temp folder for build files?

Comment: @DavidG, I tried updating `OutDir` to `C:\temp\`. Now its moving the same content under c:\temp and not moving to `PublishDir` :(